# Query MySQL with unicode char code

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, utf-16

I have been having trouble searching through a MySQL table, trying to find entries with the  character (UTF-16 code 200E) in a particular column.

This particular code doesn't have a glyph, so it doesn't seem to work when I try to paste it into my search term. Is there a way to specify characters as their respective code point instead for a query?

Thanks,
-Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char) could work for this:

```
CHAR(0x200E);
```

I can't set up a full test case right now, let us know whether it worked.

Comment: Didn't have any luck, but this might be the right path and I'm just getting some details wrong.

I tried:
     where column like CHAR(37, 0xE2808E using utf8);

0xE2808E is the UTF-8 encoding for this code point. Not sure what else I can do =/

Comment: @Ben if you're searching for that character among others, I think you need `%`: `WHERE column LIKE CONCAT("%", CHAR(0xE2808E using utf8), "%");` this could indeed be down to details and trial&error...