# How to query MySQL for fields containing null characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, escaping

I have a MySQL table with a text column.  Some rows have null characters (0x00) as part of this text column (along with other characters).

I am looking for a query that will return all rows containing any null characters for this column, but I cannot figure out how the proper syntax for my "where column like '%...%'" clause.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Right after I submitted the question, a suggested link to this related question provided my answer:
[Query MySQL with unicode char code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026651/query-mysql-with-unicode-char-code?rq=1)

WHERE column LIKE CONCAT("%", CHAR(0x00 using utf8), "%");

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me...

```sql
WHERE column LIKE "%\0%";
```